# Can I obtain the amount of allocated dynamic shared memory from within a kernel?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

On the host side, I can save the amount of dynamic shared memory I intend to launch a kernel with, and use it. I can even pass that as an argument to the kernel. But - is there a way to get it directly from device code, without help from the host side? That is, have the code for a kernel determine, as it runs, how much dynamic shared memory it has available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a special register holding that value, named [`%dynamic_smem_size`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#special-registers-dynamic-smem-size). You can obtain this register's value in your CUDA C/C++ code by wrapping some inline [PTX](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/) with a getter function:

```
__device__ unsigned dynamic_smem_size()
{
    unsigned ret; 
    asm volatile ("mov.u32 %0, %dynamic_smem_size;" : "=r"(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

You can similarly obtain the total size of allocated shared memory (static + dynamic) from the register `%total_smem_size`.